# View's layout is not entirely in the range of the primary view area

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

[image: screenshot]

When `view` is selected, the view's layout is not entirely in the range of the primary view area. How could this be possible?!

How to make the view entirely fit in the primary view area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout for the primary view controller in a double or triple column Split View includes an extra 100 points off the leading edge. This is to allow for over-scroll when swiping the primary view from the leading edge. The leading layout margin is adjusted to take account of this (and table view cells should inherit that margin). So, whilst the table view really is wider than what you see on screen, the content inside the cells themselves should appear as you would expect as long as they use the content view margins far layout. You might also need to set preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true on the cell and/or its content view.

I wrote about this here: https://indieapps.space/@adaptivity/109784939338082659